# how can I solve Django TemplateSyntaxError?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I suspect it might be due to the version of Django installed automatically by python anywhere, but if you think it's something else, please let me know if I'm missing anything.

Here's the error message populating my page, with the accompanying code issue:

```
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Unclosed tag on line 9: 'block'. 
Looking for one of: endblock.
"GET /employee/ HTTP/1.1" 500 143845
```

**Code**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Employee</title>
</head>
<body>
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<div class="row">
    {% for employeess in employees %}
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ employeess.EmployeeName }}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{ employeess.EmployeeAddress }}</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And **views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Employee

def index(request):
    employees = Employee.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'employees': employees})
```

Comment: You don't have an `{% endblock %}` tag to end the block started by the `{% block content %}` tag. Every `block` must have a `endblock`

Comment: Thanks to @IainShelvington

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I miss the  `{% endblock %}`

**New:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Employee</title>
</head>
<body>
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<div class="row">
    {% for employeess in employees %}
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ employeess.EmployeeName }}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{ employeess.EmployeeAddress }}</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
 {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```